# Terraform Azure - How to loop through each of the VMs and create a application for a different resource group and Host pool?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, terraform

I'm trying to loop through my VMs and create a application in an existing application group in Azure.
I need the IP address from each of my VMs and the name to create the resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application" "Test".
However I run into some issues for example:

> Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on main.tf line 35, in locals: │
> 35:       name = vm.name │ │ Can't access attributes on a
> primitive-typed value (string).

I barley find info's online on how to archive this, I removed data sensitive data from my code below but this is how I was trying to run it (IP command is missing since its sensistve data):

```
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vms" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Clients.name
  name = "*" 
}

locals {
  vms = [
    for vm in data.azurerm_virtual_machine.vms : {
      name = vm.name
      ip   = vm.network_interface_ids[0].private_ip_address  # Assuming the first network interface
    }
  ]
}

# Create an application for each VM
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application" "Test" {
  for_each                    = { for vm in local.vms : vm.name => vm }
  name                        = "${each.value.name}"
  application_group_id        = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.APPLICATIONGROUP.id
  friendly_name               = " ${ech.value.name}"
  path                        = "C:\\Program Files "
  show_in_portal              = true
  icon_path                   = "C:\\"
  icon_index                  = 0
}
```

Comment: isnt `azurerm_virtual_machine` a single resource, its not a list of vms so not sure what your trying to iterate over here. currently the value of vm will be an itration of each of the values in the vm resource, its not a list of vms

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for replying. Hmm I think you are right. 
Essentially I want to be able to pull the name and IP values of all VMs under the resource group Clients to essentially create a application for each VM.
I guess I could pull the info elsewhere but I was wondering if there is a way in Terraform to get the IP and name of the name into a variable to essentially build applications with this information

Comment: I mostly use AWS and dont have access to azure to test this. However you can maybe use the https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resources to search for compute/virtualMachine types in your resource group. if that works it would return you a list of resource blocks that would have the ID of each machine. You could then you the azurerm_virtual_machine data source with a foreach to look up each machine and get its specific data like name and ip

Answer (score 0):

> How to loop through each of the VMs and create a application for a different resource group and Host pool?
>
> Notes: The `azurerm_virtual_machine` data source in Terraform doesn't support wildcard or pattern matching for VM names directly within the data block.

Alternatively, you can use `PowerShell` to fetch the VM details within a resource group by using a null resource block in Terraform. The same script will export the VM details to a `JSON` file for creating the **desktop_application** with the same `VM` name..

**Script.ps1**

```
  
    $vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "<RG-Name>"
    
    # Array to store VM information objects
    $vmObjects = @()
    
    # Loop through each VM
    foreach ($vm in $vms) {
        # Get the network interface
        $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id
        $ipConfig = $nic.IpConfigurations[0]
        
        # Create a hash table for the VM information
        $vmData = @{
            "VM Name" = $vm.Name
            "Private IP" = $ipConfig.PrivateIpAddress
        }
        
        # Add the VM information hash table to the array
        $vmObjects += $vmData
    }
    
    # Convert the array of VM information hash tables to JSON and output to vms.json
    $vmObjects | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "${path.module}/vms.json"
```

**Terraform Code:**

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    resource "null_resource" "execute_powershell" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
        command = <<-EOT
          Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
          . "${path.module}/script.ps1"
        EOT
      }
      
    }
    locals {
      vm_data         = jsondecode(data.local_file.vms_json.content)
      all_vm_names    = [local.vm_data["VM Name"]]
      all_private_ips = [local.vm_data["Private IP"]]
    }
    
    data "local_file" "vms_json" {
      depends_on = [null_resource.execute_powershell]
      filename   = "${path.module}/vms.json"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "virtualdesktop-venkat1"
      location = "West Europe"
      depends_on = [null_resource.execute_powershell]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "pooledbreadthfirst" {
      name                = "pooledbreadthfirst"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      type               = "Pooled"
      load_balancer_type = "BreadthFirst"
      depends_on         = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group" "remoteapp" {
      name                = "acctag"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      type          = "RemoteApp"
      host_pool_id  = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.pooledbreadthfirst.id
      friendly_name = "TestAppGroup"
      description   = "Acceptance Test: An application group"
      depends_on    = [azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.pooledbreadthfirst]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application" "Test" {
      for_each = { for name in local.all_vm_names : name => name }
      
      name                = each.value
      application_group_id = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.remoteapp.id
      friendly_name       = each.value
      description         = "Application for VM ${each.value}"
      path                = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
      show_in_portal      = true
      command_line_argument_policy = "DoNotAllow"
      command_line_arguments       = "--incognito"
      icon_path           = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
      icon_index          = 0 
    }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]